# How can an NFT Creator Sign a transfer to a Buyer if they are not present?

Tags: metaplex, nft, minteditionfrommaster

I have built a POC platform where a 'Creator' can create NFT's (Master Editions) and mint Print Editions for sale.
Currently if you want to 'Buy' the NFT and transfer it to the Buyer, 2 signers are required. The Creator and the Buyer(Wallet).

My frontend is a React NextJs App, so no problem building the Call with the Buyer Signing it, but the Creator (is not around to sign, he busy drinking and being arty).

What is the normal way to get the Creator's Signer/Authority into the flow so that any buyer can buy his NFT's without him needing to Auth it?
We only have the Creators Public Key.

I'm using Anchor and Metaplex.

Answer (score 3):

I think the way most marketplaces do this is they have you transfer the NFT to them when it's listed, and then they can sign to transfer it to a buyer without any further interaction from the seller. The seller can of course cancel the listing and get their NFT back at any point before it sells.

With PNFTs (programmable NFTs) [there's a neat way to set a 'sale delegate' on an NFT](https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/delegates#sale-delegate-pnft-only), which allows the delegate (which would be your program) to transfer it, and stops the seller doing so or burning it. So that'd let the seller keep it in their wallet until it's sold, but also let you transfer it to the buyer.